# Combine Multiple HTML Element to One CSS Class for Show Selected State

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm relatively new to the css stuff. I have `ul` with a couple of `li` elements each `li` element contain `SVG` and `p` element.when that li is selected I want to add styling to those `li` and `SVG,p` element

```html
 <ul>
      <li>
    
        <a href="#">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            style="fill:#83868F">
            <path </svg> Infor 2</a> </li> <li class>
    
              <a href="#">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  style="fill:#83868F">
                  <path </svg> Infor 1
              </a> 
          </li>
     </ul>
```

How do I achieve this using one class? also, I want to know how to apply class dynamically to my angular component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS pseudo class:

```
a:active {
 //your styles
}
```

Also Angular provide a `[ngClass]` property that support adding dynamic class to your component. You can [read more about it here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

Comment: I went through the angular doc.they are used custom CSS classes I can't figure out how to bind this  CSS pseudo-class to the [ngClass] can you give me a small example.i would highly appreciate

Comment: It depend on the logic you want to apply, but i created a simple example that toggle the class on click: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tejwxz

Answer (score 1):

let's say you add the "`active`" class to your `<ul>` element:

```
ul.active{
  //add style here
}

ul.active li{
  //add li style here
}
ul.active svg{
  //add svg style here
}
ul.active p{
  //add p style here
}
```

Comment: this is works for all the element. I want this to apply only for selected li element. i want to apply this for  only li,svg,p.any work around

Comment: You need to add classes to every element you want to change. You can take a look at pseudoclasses too, if you only want to affect odd elements, or determined number of childs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy, let's start  first of all you can add the active class to ul SVG and p tag in the CSS and then set a variable on which you want to add them

CSS:

```
 ul.active{
  //add style here
  }
  ul.active li{
  //add li style here
  }
 ul.active svg{
  //add svg style here
 }
 ul.active p{
 //add p style here
 }
```

for example, we can add the dynamic style by setting a variable in ts, here I used "isActive".

```
  this.isActive = 0;

    onListClick(index){
          this.isActive = index;
    }
```

Also in your HTML

```
     <ul>
          <li  (click)=onListClick(index)>
            <a href="#">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="22" 
        height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                style="fill:#83868F" [ngClass]="{'active':isActive == index}">
                <path </svg> Infor 2</a> </li>

<li  (click)=onListClick(index)>
            <a href="#">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="22" 
        height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                style="fill:#83868F" [ngClass]="{'active':isActive == index}">
                <path </svg> Infor 2</a> </li>

           </ul>
```